# Для чего нужен флаг -s в gcc?

Tags: c++, c, компоновщик

Собственно ответ на вопрос я нашел:

> Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the
>   executable. (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

Нашел статью о `relocation information`:

> **relocation information**
>
> настроечная информация (информация для
>   компоновщика о том, какие конструкции в объектном файле должны быть
>   заменены адресами объектов, определенных в других исходных файлах)
>
> (http://computer_en_ru.academic.ru/36046/relocation_information)

Затем нашел ответ на вопрос, что за `symbol table` такая:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112/what-is-a-symbol-table

Но с моим знанием английского целостный взгляд на проблему так и не сложился. Может кто-то поможет собрать все части пазла в единую картину?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор помещает в исполняемый файл не только то, что нужно для запуска (то есть код и данные), но ещё и дополнительную (и в общем-то ненужную) информацию (к примеру, имена всех переменных и функций, включая те, что были объявлены со спецификатором `static`).

Эта дополнительная информация нужна только на стадии компоновки, но компилятор оставляет её и в конечном исполняемом файле, возможно для удобства дальнейшей отладки. За её вырезание и отвечает флаг `-s`.

Возьмём, к примеру, программу, состоящую из двух файлов исходных кодов:

1. `main.cpp`

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   std::string partOne("Hello, "); // Глобальная переменная

   std::string getString(); // Прототип функции, объявленной в другом файле

   int main()
   {
       std::cout << getString() << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. `other.cpp`

   ```
   #include <string>

   extern std::string partOne;
   static std::string partTwo("World!");

   std::string getString()
   {
       return partOne + partTwo;
   }
   ```
3. `CMake.txt`

   ```
   add_executable(example1 main.cpp other.cpp)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -flto")
   ```

   Флаг `-flto` я вставил для демонстрации того, что даже включение межмодульных оптимизаций не позволяет компилятору убирать какие-либо имена.

Соберём проект в режиме *Release* (`-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`) и изучим таблицу символов утилитой `nm`:

```
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
00406000 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e4 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e4 b .bss
004063e4 b .bss
004063e4 b .bss
00406020 b .bss
004063e4 b .bss
004063e4 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e4 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e4 b .bss
004063e4 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e4 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e0 b .bss
004063c0 b .bss
00406038 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063c0 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
00406080 b .bss
00406078 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
00406078 b .bss
00406044 b .bss
0040606c b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
00406044 b .bss
00406068 b .bss
00406068 b .bss
00406044 b .bss
00406068 b .bss
00406064 b .bss
00406064 b .bss
00406044 b .bss
00406064 b .bss
00406044 b .bss
00406060 b .bss
00406060 b .bss
00406044 b .bss
0040605c b .bss
00406058 b .bss
00406044 b .bss
00406054 b .bss
00406044 b .bss
00406044 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
00406044 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
004063e8 b .bss
00408000 d .CRT$XCA
00408004 d .CRT$XCAA
00408008 d .CRT$XCZ
0040802c d .CRT$XDA
00408030 d .CRT$XDZ
0040800c d .CRT$XIA
00408010 d .CRT$XIAA
00408014 d .CRT$XIC
00408018 d .CRT$XIZ
0040801c d .CRT$XLA
00408020 d .CRT$XLC
00408024 d .CRT$XLD
00408028 d .CRT$XLZ
00402914 t .ctors
00402918 t .ctors.65535
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403000 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403020 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403020 d .data
00403020 d .data
00403004 d .data
00403020 d .data
00403020 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403020 d .data
0040301c d .data
00403028 d .data
0040301c d .data
0040301c d .data
00403028 d .data
00403004 d .data
0040301c d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403004 d .data
0040301c d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403018 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403018 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403014 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403004 d .data
00403014 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403014 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403004 d .data
00403014 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403014 d .data
00403004 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403014 d .data
00403014 d .data
0040300c d .data
00403004 d .data
00403004 d .data
00403008 d .data
00403008 d .data
00403008 d .data
00403004 d .data
00403008 d .data
00403004 d .data
00403004 d .data
00403004 d .data
0040301c d .data
00403028 d .data
00403008 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403028 d .data
00403004 d .data
00403028 d .data$__security_cookie
0040302c d .data$__security_cookie_complement
0040c000 N .debug_abbrev
0040c014 N .debug_abbrev
0040a020 N .debug_aranges
0040a000 N .debug_aranges
0040e000 N .debug_frame
0040b0b3 N .debug_info
0040b000 N .debug_info
0040d077 N .debug_line
0040d000 N .debug_line
004055d8 r .eh_frame
00405298 r .eh_frame
004058a0 r .eh_frame
004053e0 r .eh_frame
00405000 r .eh_frame
0040543c r .eh_frame
004053b4 r .eh_frame
004054d0 r .eh_frame
004052c4 r .eh_frame
0040521c r .eh_frame
00405128 r .eh_frame
00405304 r .eh_frame
00405360 r .eh_frame
00405564 r .eh_frame
004054fc r .eh_frame
004050c8 r .eh_frame
004056b0 r .eh_frame
004058e0 r .eh_frame
00402928 t .gcc_except_table
00407028 i .idata$2
00407000 i .idata$2
0040703c i .idata$2
00407014 i .idata$2
00407184 i .idata$4
00407120 i .idata$4
00407130 i .idata$4
00407128 i .idata$4
004070d0 i .idata$4
00407064 i .idata$4
00407168 i .idata$4
0040714c i .idata$4
004070f4 i .idata$4
0040708c i .idata$4
00407094 i .idata$4
004070f0 i .idata$4
00407104 i .idata$4
00407070 i .idata$4
004070c8 i .idata$4
0040716c i .idata$4
004070cc i .idata$4
004070a0 i .idata$4
00407080 i .idata$4
004070e0 i .idata$4
00407138 i .idata$4
004070fc i .idata$4
00407068 i .idata$4
0040709c i .idata$4
00407124 i .idata$4
0040717c i .idata$4
00407064 i .idata$4
00407140 i .idata$4
004070ec i .idata$4
004070b8 i .idata$4
00407158 i .idata$4
0040712c i .idata$4
004070a8 i .idata$4
00407114 i .idata$4
00407148 i .idata$4
00407108 i .idata$4
0040707c i .idata$4
0040711c i .idata$4
004070b0 i .idata$4
00407118 i .idata$4
00407134 i .idata$4
0040713c i .idata$4
00407174 i .idata$4
00407148 i .idata$4
00407164 i .idata$4
00407078 i .idata$4
004070bc i .idata$4
00407180 i .idata$4
004070e8 i .idata$4
00407170 i .idata$4
00407084 i .idata$4
00407098 i .idata$4
00407178 i .idata$4
00407090 i .idata$4
004070b4 i .idata$4
004070c4 i .idata$4
0040706c i .idata$4
00407088 i .idata$4
004070d4 i .idata$4
00407078 i .idata$4
004070d8 i .idata$4
004070c0 i .idata$4
0040715c i .idata$4
00407150 i .idata$4
004070d8 i .idata$4
00407110 i .idata$4
0040710c i .idata$4
00407154 i .idata$4
004070f8 i .idata$4
00407074 i .idata$4
004070e4 i .idata$4
00407160 i .idata$4
00407100 i .idata$4
004070ac i .idata$4
00407144 i .idata$4
004070dc i .idata$4
004070a4 i .idata$4
004071a0 i .idata$5
004071a8 i .idata$5
004071d0 i .idata$5
004071f0 i .idata$5
00407234 i .idata$5
004071e4 i .idata$5
00407278 i .idata$5
00407274 i .idata$5
004071fc i .idata$5
004071ac i .idata$5
00407224 i .idata$5
00407190 i .idata$5
004071d8 i .idata$5
00407200 i .idata$5
00407208 i .idata$5
004071b4 i .idata$5
004071ec i .idata$5
0040719c i .idata$5
0040729c i .idata$5
004071f8 i .idata$5
004071e0 i .idata$5
00407240 i .idata$5
004071fc i .idata$5
00407238 i .idata$5
00407258 i .idata$5
004071e8 i .idata$5
004072a4 i .idata$5
00407298 i .idata$5
004071f4 i .idata$5
00407288 i .idata$5
00407260 i .idata$5
0040720c i .idata$5
004072a0 i .idata$5
00407188 i .idata$5
00407280 i .idata$5
00407290 i .idata$5
00407250 i .idata$5
004071b0 i .idata$5
004071cc i .idata$5
004071dc i .idata$5
00407284 i .idata$5
0040722c i .idata$5
0040718c i .idata$5
0040725c i .idata$5
00407264 i .idata$5
00407248 i .idata$5
00407204 i .idata$5
00407228 i .idata$5
00407194 i .idata$5
004071c0 i .idata$5
0040728c i .idata$5
00407188 i .idata$5
004072a8 i .idata$5
0040726c i .idata$5
00407254 i .idata$5
00407214 i .idata$5
004071c4 i .idata$5
004071a4 i .idata$5
004071b8 i .idata$5
00407218 i .idata$5
00407270 i .idata$5
0040719c i .idata$5
00407244 i .idata$5
00407198 i .idata$5
0040724c i .idata$5
00407210 i .idata$5
004071d4 i .idata$5
0040726c i .idata$5
0040723c i .idata$5
0040721c i .idata$5
00407220 i .idata$5
004071bc i .idata$5
004071c8 i .idata$5
00407294 i .idata$5
00407268 i .idata$5
00407230 i .idata$5
0040727c i .idata$5
00407724 i .idata$6
00407562 i .idata$6
004074d0 i .idata$6
004076a8 i .idata$6
004075a4 i .idata$6
00407374 i .idata$6
0040738a i .idata$6
004072f4 i .idata$6
00407540 i .idata$6
0040759c i .idata$6
00407708 i .idata$6
004077b8 i .idata$6
004075ae i .idata$6
004074a2 i .idata$6
004072c0 i .idata$6
004074fe i .idata$6
004075c0 i .idata$6
00407610 i .idata$6
004073ec i .idata$6
00407324 i .idata$6
00407580 i .idata$6
004075fa i .idata$6
0040751a i .idata$6
0040735e i .idata$6
00407480 i .idata$6
00407790 i .idata$6
004075c8 i .idata$6
00407494 i .idata$6
004074e0 i .idata$6
004074ee i .idata$6
00407674 i .idata$6
0040756c i .idata$6
00407418 i .idata$6
0040750a i .idata$6
00407592 i .idata$6
00407664 i .idata$6
004076e0 i .idata$6
004072dc i .idata$6
0040730c i .idata$6
00407478 i .idata$6
00407604 i .idata$6
004073d2 i .idata$6
00407740 i .idata$6
004075e6 i .idata$6
004075b6 i .idata$6
004073fc i .idata$6
004075d2 i .idata$6
0040745a i .idata$6
00407634 i .idata$6
00407440 i .idata$6
0040754a i .idata$6
004072ac i .idata$6
004076cc i .idata$6
004075f0 i .idata$6
0040733c i .idata$6
0040734a i .idata$6
004074be i .idata$6
004073c0 i .idata$6
004076f8 i .idata$6
00407578 i .idata$6
004075dc i .idata$6
0040739a i .idata$6
00407684 i .idata$6
004073ae i .idata$6
004077ac i .idata$6
00407430 i .idata$6
0040752c i .idata$6
00407558 i .idata$6
00407588 i .idata$6
00407910 i .idata$7
004078a8 i .idata$7
004078a4 i .idata$7
004078f0 i .idata$7
004078e0 i .idata$7
004078e8 i .idata$7
0040791c i .idata$7
004078dc i .idata$7
0040786c i .idata$7
004078b0 i .idata$7
004078c4 i .idata$7
00407858 i .idata$7
00407820 i .idata$7
0040788c i .idata$7
00407934 i .idata$7
00407870 i .idata$7
004078cc i .idata$7
00407924 i .idata$7
00407898 i .idata$7
00407890 i .idata$7
004078a0 i .idata$7
00407834 i .idata$7
00407928 i .idata$7
004078bc i .idata$7
004078ac i .idata$7
004078c8 i .idata$7
00407848 i .idata$7
0040789c i .idata$7
00407804 i .idata$7
004078d4 i .idata$7
004078b8 i .idata$7
004077fc i .idata$7
00407830 i .idata$7
004078ec i .idata$7
004078d8 i .idata$7
00407874 i .idata$7
00407868 i .idata$7
00407888 i .idata$7
00407930 i .idata$7
0040790c i .idata$7
0040782c i .idata$7
00407828 i .idata$7
00407938 i .idata$7
00407850 i .idata$7
004078c0 i .idata$7
004078f4 i .idata$7
00407908 i .idata$7
00407800 i .idata$7
00407894 i .idata$7
0040781c i .idata$7
00407860 i .idata$7
004078e4 i .idata$7
0040792c i .idata$7
0040784c i .idata$7
004077f8 i .idata$7
0040785c i .idata$7
00407918 i .idata$7
00407920 i .idata$7
004078b4 i .idata$7
00407840 i .idata$7
0040793c i .idata$7
00407824 i .idata$7
00407838 i .idata$7
00407914 i .idata$7
00407808 i .idata$7
00407844 i .idata$7
00407854 i .idata$7
00407878 i .idata$7
0040783c i .idata$7
004078d0 i .idata$7
00407904 i .idata$7
00407900 i .idata$7
00407864 i .idata$7
00403030 d .jcr
00403030 d .jcr
00404064 r .rdata
004041ac r .rdata
00404078 r .rdata
004042ac r .rdata
004042a4 r .rdata
00404074 r .rdata
00404000 r .rdata
00404730 r .rdata$zzz
00404370 r .rdata$zzz
004043b0 r .rdata$zzz
004043f0 r .rdata$zzz
00404430 r .rdata$zzz
00404470 r .rdata$zzz
004044b0 r .rdata$zzz
004044f0 r .rdata$zzz
00404530 r .rdata$zzz
004048f0 r .rdata$zzz
00404570 r .rdata$zzz
004045b0 r .rdata$zzz
004045f0 r .rdata$zzz
00404630 r .rdata$zzz
00404670 r .rdata$zzz
004046b0 r .rdata$zzz
00404930 r .rdata$zzz
004046f0 r .rdata$zzz
004048b0 r .rdata$zzz
004042f0 r .rdata$zzz
00404870 r .rdata$zzz
00404770 r .rdata$zzz
004047b0 r .rdata$zzz
004047f0 r .rdata$zzz
004042b0 r .rdata$zzz
00404830 r .rdata$zzz
00404330 r .rdata$zzz
00404970 r .rdata_runtime_pseudo_reloc
004026d8 t .text
004027d0 t .text
00402390 t .text
     U .text
     U .text
     U .text
     U .text
004026e0 t .text
00402390 t .text
004027c8 t .text
004027d8 t .text
00402140 t .text
00401500 t .text
00402778 t .text
     U .text
0040270c t .text
004027d8 t .text
00402140 t .text
00402778 t .text
00402780 t .text
00402000 t .text
     U .text
004026d0 t .text
00402788 t .text
0040270c t .text
004027d8 t .text
00401f60 t .text
     U .text
     U .text
00402790 t .text
00401610 t .text
004027a8 t .text
0040270c t .text
     U .text
004027c0 t .text
00401f50 t .text
0040270c t .text
00402798 t .text
00401b10 t .text
     U .text
     U .text
0040270c t .text
00402798 t .text
00401a50 t .text
     U .text
0040270c t .text
00402714 t .text
     U .text
00401a40 t .text
     U .text
00401a40 t .text
00402720 t .text
004018f0 t .text
004027b8 t .text
     U .text
004018f0 t .text
00402740 t .text
004018f0 t .text
00402748 t .text
004018f0 t .text
00402750 t .text
     U .text
00401810 t .text
00402758 t .text
00401810 t .text
00402760 t .text
004017f0 t .text
00402768 t .text
     U .text
004017e0 t .text
004027b0 t .text
00401000 t .text
00401680 t .text
     U .text
00402770 t .text
     U .text
00401700 t .text
00401688 t .text
00401690 t .text
00401690 t .text
004016f8 t .text
00401690 t .text
     U .text
004016f0 t .text
     U .text
004016e8 t .text
00401698 t .text
004016e0 t .text
004016a0 t .text
     U .text
004016d8 t .text
004016a8 t .text
004016d0 t .text
004016a8 t .text
004016c8 t .text
     U .text
     U .text
004016c0 t .text
004016b0 t .text
004016b8 t .text
004027a0 t .text
004027e0 t .text.startup
004028f0 t .text.startup
00409004 d .tls
00409000 d .tls$AAA
0040901c d .tls$ZZZ
00000000 A .weak.___deregister_frame_info._hmod_libgcc
00000000 A .weak.___register_frame_info._hmod_libgcc
00000000 A .weak.__Jv_RegisterClasses._hmod_libgcc
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
00000001 a @feat.00
004021c0 T ____w64_mingwthr_add_key_dtor
00402250 T ____w64_mingwthr_remove_key_dtor
004026e0 T ___chkstk_ms
0040800c D ___crt_xc_end__
00408000 D ___crt_xc_start__
0040801c D ___crt_xi_end__
0040800c D ___crt_xi_start__
0040801c D ___crt_xl_start__
0040802c D ___crt_xp_end__
0040802c D ___crt_xp_start__
0040802c D ___crt_xt_end__
0040802c D ___crt_xt_start__
00402910 T ___CTOR_LIST__
004026d0 T ___deregister_frame_info
00402780 T ___dllonexit
00401f90 T ___do_global_ctors
00401f60 T ___do_global_dtors
00402920 T ___DTOR_LIST__
00401700 t ___dyn_tls_dtor@12
00401750 T ___dyn_tls_init@12
00404074 R ___dyn_tls_init_callback
004050c8 r ___EH_FRAME_BEGIN__
004058e0 r ___FRAME_END__
004015b0 T ___gcc_deregister_frame
00401680 T ___gcc_personality_v0
00401500 T ___gcc_register_frame
00402714 T ___getmainargs
00400000 A ___ImageBase
00403030 d ___JCR_END__
00403030 d ___JCR_LIST__
00000000 A ___lconv_init
00401fe0 T ___main
00402630 T ___mingw_enum_import_library_names
00402500 T ___mingw_GetSectionCount
004024b0 T ___mingw_GetSectionForAddress
00401000 t ___mingw_invalidParameterHandler
00406064 B ___mingw_oldexcpt_handler
00408014 D ___mingw_pinit
00401a50 T ___mingw_raise_matherr
00401aa0 T ___mingw_setusermatherr
004022f0 T ___mingw_TLScallback
004063ec B ___mingw_winmain_hInstance
004063e8 B ___mingw_winmain_lpCmdLine
00403000 D ___mingw_winmain_nShowCmd
004063c8 b ___mingwthr_cs
004063c4 b ___mingwthr_cs_init
00402140 t ___mingwthr_run_key_dtors.part.0
00403010 D ___native_dllmain_reason
004063fc B ___native_startup_lock
00406400 B ___native_startup_state
0040300c D ___native_vcclrit_reason
004063f8 B ___onexitbegin
004063f4 B ___onexitend
004026d8 T ___register_frame_info
00401b10 t ___report_error
004020b0 T ___report_gsfailure
00404970 A ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__
00404988 R ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__
00403028 D ___security_cookie
0040302c D ___security_cookie_complement
00402000 T ___security_init_cookie
0040270c T ___set_app_type
00402798 T ___setusermatherr
00401610 t ___tcf_0.lto_priv.6
00401620 t ___tcf_0.lto_priv.7
00401650 t ___tcf_1
004017d0 T ___tlregdtor
00409020 D ___tls_end__
00409000 D ___tls_start__
00401180 t ___tmainCRTStartup
00408000 D ___xc_a
00408008 D ___xc_z
0040802c d ___xd_a
00408030 d ___xd_z
0040800c D ___xi_a
00408018 D ___xi_z
0040801c D ___xl_a
00408020 D ___xl_c
00408024 D ___xl_d
00408028 D ___xl_z
00402760 T __amsg_exit
00406414 B __bss_end__
00406000 B __bss_start__
00402758 T __cexit
00403004 D __charmax
00403018 D __CRT_MT
00402910 T __CTOR_LIST__
00403034 D __data_end__
00403000 D __data_start__
004017f0 T __decode_pointer
00000000 A __dll__
00000000 A __dll_characteristics__
00403008 D __dowildcard
00402920 T __DTOR_LIST__
00401800 T __encode_pointer
0040a000 D __end__
00000200 A __file_alignment__
004023d0 T __FindPESection
00402410 T __FindPESectionByName
00402530 T __FindPESectionExec
0040605c B __fmode
00401f50 T __fpreset
00402898 T __fu0___ZSt4cout
00402720 T __get_invalid_parameter_handler
004025a0 T __GetPEImageBase
004027e0 t __GLOBAL__I_65535_0_objects.a_0xd0.3181
004018f0 T __gnu_exception_handler@4
00407014 I __head_lib32_libkernel32_a
00407028 I __head_lib32_libmsvcrt_a
00407000 I __head_libgcc_s_dw2_1_dll
0040703c I __head_libstdc___6_dll
004072ac I __IAT_end__
00407188 I __IAT_start__
00400000 A __image_base__
0040718c I __imp____deregister_frame_info
004071fc I __imp____dllonexit
00407190 I __imp____gcc_personality_v0
00407200 I __imp____getmainargs
00407204 I __imp____initenv
00407208 I __imp____lconv_init
00407194 I __imp____register_frame_info
0040720c I __imp____set_app_type
00407210 I __imp____setusermatherr
00407214 I __imp___acmdln
00407218 I __imp___amsg_exit
0040721c I __imp___cexit
00407220 I __imp___fmode
00403020 D __imp___get_invalid_parameter_handler
00407224 I __imp___initterm
00407228 I __imp___iob
0040722c I __imp___lock
00407230 I __imp___onexit
00403024 D __imp___set_invalid_parameter_handler
00407234 I __imp___unlock
00407188 I __imp___Unwind_Resume
0040726c I __imp___ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv
00407270 I __imp___ZNKSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5widenEc
00407274 I __imp___ZNSo3putEc
00407278 I __imp___ZNSo5flushEv
0040727c I __imp___ZNSs4_Rep10_M_destroyERKSaIcE
00407280 I __imp___ZNSs4_Rep10_M_disposeERKSaIcE
00407284 I __imp___ZNSs6appendERKSs
00407288 I __imp___ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE
0040728c I __imp___ZNSsC1ERKSs
00407290 I __imp___ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
00407294 I __imp___ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
00407298 I __imp___ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
0040729c I __imp___ZSt16__throw_bad_castv
004072a0 I __imp___ZSt4cout
004072a0 I __imp___ZSt4cout
004072a4 I __imp___ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
00407238 I __imp__abort
0040723c I __imp__calloc
0040719c I __imp__DeleteCriticalSection@4
004071a0 I __imp__EnterCriticalSection@4
00407240 I __imp__exit
00407244 I __imp__fprintf
00407248 I __imp__free
004071a4 I __imp__FreeLibrary@4
0040724c I __imp__fwrite
004071a8 I __imp__GetCurrentProcess@0
004071ac I __imp__GetCurrentProcessId@0
004071b0 I __imp__GetCurrentThreadId@0
004071b4 I __imp__GetLastError@0
004071b8 I __imp__GetModuleHandleA@4
004071bc I __imp__GetProcAddress@8
004071c0 I __imp__GetStartupInfoA@4
004071c4 I __imp__GetSystemTimeAsFileTime@4
004071c8 I __imp__GetTickCount@0
004071cc I __imp__InitializeCriticalSection@4
004071d0 I __imp__LeaveCriticalSection@4
004071d4 I __imp__LoadLibraryA@4
00407250 I __imp__malloc
00407254 I __imp__memcpy
004071d8 I __imp__QueryPerformanceCounter@4
004071dc I __imp__SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4
00407258 I __imp__signal
004071e0 I __imp__Sleep@4
0040725c I __imp__strlen
00407260 I __imp__strncmp
004071e4 I __imp__TerminateProcess@8
004071e8 I __imp__TlsGetValue@4
004071ec I __imp__UnhandledExceptionFilter@4
00407264 I __imp__vfprintf
004071f0 I __imp__VirtualProtect@16
004071f4 I __imp__VirtualQuery@12
00402768 T __initterm
004025d0 T __IsNonwritableInCurrentImage
     U __Jv_RegisterClasses
00407878 I __lib32_libkernel32_a_iname
004078f4 I __lib32_libmsvcrt_a_iname
00000000 A __loader_flags__
00402778 T __lock
00000000 A __major_image_version__
00000004 A __major_os_version__
00000004 A __major_subsystem_version__
00401ab0 T __matherr
0040301c D __MINGW_INSTALL_DEBUG_MATHERR
00000000 A __minor_image_version__
00000000 A __minor_os_version__
00000000 A __minor_subsystem_version__
00406060 B __newmode
004077ac I __nm___ZSt4cout
00401cb0 T __pei386_runtime_relocator
00404988 R __rt_psrelocs_end
00000018 A __rt_psrelocs_size
00404970 R __rt_psrelocs_start
00404970 A __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__
00404988 R __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__
00001000 A __section_alignment__
00402730 T __set_invalid_parameter_handler
00401a40 T __setargv
00001000 A __size_of_heap_commit__
00100000 A __size_of_heap_reserve__
00001000 A __size_of_stack_commit__
00200000 A __size_of_stack_reserve__
00000003 A __subsystem__
0040901c D __tls_end
00406050 B __tls_index
00409000 D __tls_start
00409004 D __tls_used
00402788 T __unlock
00401688 T __Unwind_Resume
004023b0 T __ValidateImageBase
00402390 t __ValidateImageBase.part.0
00000000 A __Z9getStringv
00406038 b __ZL7partTwo
004016c8 T __ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv
00000000 A __ZNKSt5ctypeIcE8do_widenEc
00401698 T __ZNKSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5widenEc
004016e0 T __ZNSo3putEc
004016d8 T __ZNSo5flushEv
004016a8 T __ZNSs4_Rep10_M_destroyERKSaIcE
00401690 T __ZNSs4_Rep10_M_disposeERKSaIcE
004016f0 T __ZNSs6appendERKSs
004016b0 T __ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE
004016f8 T __ZNSsC1ERKSs
004016b8 T __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
004016c0 T __ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
004016e8 T __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
004016d0 T __ZSt16__throw_bad_castv
004016a0 T __ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
00406040 b __ZStL8__ioinit
00000000 A __ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEESbIT_T0_T1_ERKS6_S8_
004027b8 T _abort
0040601c b _argc
00406010 b _argret
00406018 b _argv
004018d0 T _atexit
004027c0 T _calloc
00404194 r _CSWTCH.5
00000000 A _DeleteCriticalSection@4
00000000 A _EnterCriticalSection@4
00406014 b _envp
00402770 T _exit
00401f50 T _fpreset
004027a0 T _fprintf
004027c8 T _free
00000000 A _FreeLibrary@4
004027a8 T _fwrite
00000000 A _GetCurrentProcess@0
00000000 A _GetCurrentProcessId@0
00000000 A _GetCurrentThreadId@0
00000000 A _GetLastError@0
00000000 A _GetModuleHandleA@4
00000000 A _GetProcAddress@8
00000000 A _GetStartupInfoA@4
00000000 A _GetSystemTimeAsFileTime@4
00000000 A _GetTickCount@0
00406080 b _GS_ContextRecord
004042a4 r _GS_ExceptionPointers
00406360 b _GS_ExceptionRecord
004063e4 b _handler
00406004 b _has_cctor
004063f0 B _hmod_libgcc
00000000 A _InitializeCriticalSection@4
00406078 b _initialized
004063c0 b _key_dtor_list
00000000 A _LeaveCriticalSection@4
00407808 I _libgcc_s_dw2_1_dll_iname
0040793c I _libstdc___6_dll_iname
00000000 A _LoadLibraryA@4
00402850 T _main
004014e0 T _mainCRTStartup
0040600c b _mainret
00402740 T _malloc
00406008 b _managedapp
00401b70 t _mark_section_writable
00406070 b _maxSections
00402750 T _memcpy
00406058 B _mingw_app_type
00402720 t _mingw_get_invalid_parameter_handler
00406054 B _mingw_initcharmax
0040604c B _mingw_initltsdrot_force
00406048 B _mingw_initltsdyn_force
00406044 B _mingw_initltssuo_force
00401810 T _mingw_onexit
00408010 D _mingw_pcinit
00408004 D _mingw_pcppinit
00402730 t _mingw_set_invalid_parameter_handler
004017e0 t _my_lconv_init
00406020 b _obj
00403014 d _p.59329
0040603c b _partOne
00000000 A _partOne
00401010 t _pre_c_init
00401130 t _pre_cpp_init
00000000 A _QueryPerformanceCounter@4
004028f0 t _register_frame_ctor
00000000 A _SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4
00402790 T _signal
00000000 A _Sleep@4
00406000 b _startinfo
00402748 T _strlen
004027d0 T _strncmp
00406068 b _stUserMathErr
00000000 A _TerminateProcess@8
00406074 b _the_secs
00000000 A _TlsGetValue@4
00000000 A _UnhandledExceptionFilter@4
004027b0 T _vfprintf
00000000 A _VirtualProtect@16
00000000 A _VirtualQuery@12
0040606c b _was_init.60615
004014c0 T _WinMainCRTStartup
004071fc i fthunk
0040719c i fthunk
00407078 i hname
004070d8 i hname
```

Не кажется, что это как-то слишком много для программы, которая ничего не экспортирует в духе DLL?

Заодно запомним размер программы: 52 105 байт.

Теперь несколько изменим `CMakeList.txt`:

```
add_executable(example2 main.cpp other.cpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -flto -s")
```

Мы добавили флаг `-s` и изменили имя исполняемого файла. Теперь после сборки программы `nm` выдаёт следующее:

```
nm: example2.exe: no symbols
```

То есть программе для работы не требуется *ни одно* из 1 001 вышеупомянутого имени!

А что с объёмом? 16 896 байт. То есть мы смогли безболезненно уменьшить размер программы в три раза! И это для двух простых объектных файлов. При усложнении же проекта доля имён от размера исполняемого файла будет ещё больше.

*Кстати, вы заметили, что бо́льшую часть символов занимают имена секций? Так вот, это следствие различия форматов объектных (ELF) и исполняемых (PE EXE) файлов при сборке под MinGW, не позволяющего объединить эти имена и использовать их по прямому назначению. Также в таблице имён фигурирует большое количество символов из объектных файлов стандартной библиотеки.*

---

*При написании данного ответа использовались следующие версии программ:*

- *CMake 3.4.0,*
- *GCC 4.9.2 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project),*
- *GNU nm (GNU Binutils) 2.24.*