# g++ - Гигантский размер файла после компоновки

Tags: c++, g++

Моя программа - обычный "Hello World", но когда я компилирую её, она начинает весить 11Мб. Это происходит после компоновки, т.к main.o (Только компиляция и ассемблирование) весит 2Кб.

Я использую последнюю версию gcc (9.1.0)

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << "test test" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Параметры g++ без линкера

```
g++ main.cpp -c
```

Параметры g++ с линкером

```
g++ main.cpp -o test
```

Comment: Скомпилировал в своей убунточке 18.04 — получил файл 8 килобайт ¯\\(°_o)/¯

Comment: Скомпилировал на Windows, получил 16 килобайт ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Винда, MinGW/GCC 9.1 x64 - 320 кб. На какой вы ОС, и что выводит `g++ --version`?

Comment: может у вас статик рантайм прилинковался?

Comment: Вы что-то от нас скрываете

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Для чего нужен флаг -s в gcc?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668598/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3-s-%d0%b2-gcc)